# Javaは何言語で書かれていますか？

Tags: java

英語で検索したのですが、翻訳がうまく働かずはっきりとした回答を得ることができませんでした
スタックオーバーフローだったのでここで質問すれば解決しますか

Comment: 質問が曖昧です。プログラミング言語Javaの国際規格については英語で提供されていますが、おそらく質問内容は規格についてではないように見えます。
Java言語で書かれたテキストファイル(ソースコード)使って、アプリケーションとして動作させるには、Java言語で書かれたソースコードを中間コードに変換するコンパイラと、中間コードをアプリケーションとして実行する実行環境が必要になりますが、表題の「java」は何を指しているのか明確ではないため、解答できないかと。

Comment: 実際には何言語で書かれていようが、別の言語を使って実装することができるという意味では誰かが何かで書いているかもしれない。一旦別の言語を使ってjavaコンパイラを作成したらそれを使うこともできるという意味でjava自身でもよいし。そういう意味で言うと、「javaは何言語で書かれていますか？」という質問はあまり意味がないような気がします。質問意図は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 34):

OracleのJavaについて大ざっぱに回答すると、現在はOracleのHotSpot JVMはC++で書かれています。（参照: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/）
コンパイラの`javac`はJavaで書かれています。（参照: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/）
標準クラスライブラリは主にJavaで書かれていて、一部のネイティブメソッドとして実装されているものはC++で書かれています。